# What is the source of MATLAB error sounds?

Tags: matlab

`beep off` only removes some sounds - e.g. not when I press down arrow in empty console.

I followed [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1804068/1010638) to try to eliminate it via registry keys, to no avail. I've not tried deleting the sound file (last I did it I got BSOD a week later), but I verified MATLAB doesn't keep a copy of the file somewhere using [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/downloads/) (at least without renaming).

How does MATLAB play error sounds? Is it by "asking" the system? Windows 11

Comment: Is the question how does MATLAB play the sounds (I don't know, but possibly proprietary info), or how to control the sounds?

Comment: In any case, the question here (albeit very old, 2012) suggests that indeed is the OS sound that is played: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/36303-can-the-beep-be-turned-off-within-matlab

Comment: The goal is to stop it from playing that sound entirely, so a universal `beep off` - I'll reformat the question if you have the answer

Comment: Unfortunately everything suggests that you can't, unless you indeed disable it from the OS. Which is a fairly bad design decision by Mathworks, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 11:

- **File**: `C:\Windows\media\Windows Background.wav`
- **Applet**: `Control Panel` (View by: Large icons) > `Sound` > `Sounds` > `Default Beep`
- **Registry**: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\.Default\.Current`

Thanks @AnderBiguri for linking a discussion [thread](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/36303-can-the-beep-be-turned-off-within-matlab) - I verified that setting `Default Beep` to `(None)` eliminates the beep (but does so for *all* applications that use it). For a MATLAB-specific attempt, see [here](https://superuser.com/a/1804068/1010638).